# Serialize Sql View into OData complex objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have a view with a query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    p.[Id] AS Id,
    ProductName,
    [ProductDescription],
    [color],
    [image] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[products] p 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[productInfos] pp ON p.Id = pp.Pid
```

I have created a corresponding entity model shown here:

```
[Table("V_Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }       
}
```

When I call the OData endpoint, I get the response as below:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:60553/$metadata#Products",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "ProductName": "Running Clinch-X Shoes",
            "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
            "color": "blue",
            "image": "/assets/img/menshoe.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "ProductName": "Football Nemeziz 19.3 Turf Boots",
            "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
            "color": "Black",
            "image": "/assets/img/black.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "ProductName": "Originals USA 84 Shoes",
            "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
            "color": "white",
            "image": "/assets/img/white.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "ProductName": "Running Remit Shoes",
            "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
            "color": "grey",
            "image": "/assets/img/grey.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change this response to look like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:60553/$metadata#Products",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "ProductName": "Running Clinch-X Shoes",
            "ProductInfo": {
                "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
                "color": "blue",
                "image": "/assets/img/menshoe.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "ProductName": "Football Nemeziz 19.3 Turf Boots",
            "ProductInfo": {
                "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
                "color": "Black",
                "image": "/assets/img/black.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "ProductName": "Originals USA 84 Shoes",
            "ProductInfo": {
                "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
                "color": "white",
                "image": "/assets/img/white.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "ProductName": "Running Remit Shoes",
            "ProductInfo": {
                "ProductDescription": "Men Shoes",
                "color": "grey",
                "image": "/assets/img/grey.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I know one solution is to create separate views and add `[AutoExpand]` to the child entities. But the select query I am dealing with is much more bigger and I may end up creating many many views which would be complex to manage.

Is there anything I can do in the entity model or within the code that can help me get the desired result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am hoping I am clear with what I am asking here. Basically, I want to customize the response to sub object although the actual query is only one.

Comment: Out of the box odata is relational so if you didn't have to deal with the views then you could have built a query like $products?$expand=productInfo, i think you are going to have to build a custom action here and map the entity response to a dto.

Comment: Problem with mapping to a dto, is I may not be able to leverage OData functionality, like $select. I was thinking there could be some Attribute or have subclasses that can help achieve this.